# Powershell - Regex match multiple lines from file

Tags: regex, powershell

I am able to match and replace multiple lines if the text string is part of the powsershell script:

```
$regex = @"
(?s)(--match from here--.*?
--up to here--)
"@

$text = @"
first line
--match from here--
other lines
--up to here--
last line
"@

$editedText = ($text -replace $regex, "")
$editedText | Set-Content ".\output.txt"
```

output.txt:

```
first line

last line
```

But if I instead read the text in from a file with Get-Content -Raw, the same regex fails to match anything.

```
$text = Get-Content ".\input.txt" -Raw
```

input.txt:

```
first line
--match from here--
other lines
--up to here--
last line
```

output.txt:

```
first line
--match from here--
other lines
--up to here--
last line
```

Why is this? What can I do to match the text read in from input.txt? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check line breaks in text file match those of PS script or don't use hardcoded line breaks in RegEx but `\r?\n` to match all kind of line breaks: `(?s)(--match from here--.*?\r?\n--up to here--)`

Comment: `Get-Content` return a list of strings (`string[]`) by default which will all hold against your regex. The `-Raw` parameter causes `Get-Content` to join all the lines with a newline character(s) which causes your regex to fail. **Why do you want to use the `-Raw` parameter?** (The nice thing of the default behavior, is that the lines are streamed and therefore use less memory in a correctly setup [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines))

Comment: If the goal is to match lines in between two lines *in a stream*, have a look at the prototype in this propose: [`#15136` Add `-From` and `-To` parameters to `Select-String`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15136): `Get-Content ".\input.txt" |SelectString -From '--match from here--' -To '--up to here--'`

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a here-string the code depends on the kind of newline characters used by the .ps1 file. It won't work if it doesn't match the newline characters used by the input file.

To remove this dependency, define a RegEx that uses `\r?\n` to match all kinds of newlines:

```
$regex = "(?s)(--match from here--.*?\r?\n--up to here--)"

$text = Get-Content "input.txt" -Raw

$editedText = $text -replace $regex, ""

$editedText | Set-Content ".\output.txt"
```

---

Alternatively you may use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) based solution, so you can use simpler RegEx pattern:

```
$include = $true
& { switch -File 'input.txt' -RegEx { 
    '--match from here--' { $include = $false } 
    { $include }          { $_ }  # Output line if $include equals $true
    '--up to here--'      { $include = $true }
}} | Set-Content 'output.txt'
```

The `switch -File` construct loops over all lines of the input file and passes each one to the match expressions.

When we find the 1st pattern we set an `$include` flag to `$false`, which causes the code to skip over all lines until after the 2nd pattern is found, which sets the `$include` flag back to `$true`.

Writing `$_` on its own causes the current line to be outputted.

We pipe to `Set-Content` to reduce memory footprint of the script. Instead of reading all lines into a variable in memory, we use a streaming approach where each processed line is immediately passed to `Set-Content`. Note that we can't pipe directly from a `switch` block, so as workaround we wrap the `switch` inside a script block (`& { ... }` creates and calls the script block).

The idea has been adopted from [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15136#issuecomment-812288484).

Comment: Thank you!! Was stuck trying all sorts of things for ages based on other answers I found (I am very new to powershell scripting). So it was just that the linebreak type in my regex statement was not matching the linebreak type in the input file, for whatever reason.. it must be that, because your solution works, and also .*? alone matches the linebreak too, as long as I don't have a linebreak in the regex. 

So this is also working for me: 
$regex = "(?s)(--match from here--.*?--up to here--)"

Thanks again!